# Doctrine association persist

Tags: doctrine-orm, associations

I have a problem with doctrine. I have two entities.

FriendRequest

```
class FriendRequest
{

/** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
protected $id;

/**
 * First person from friendship
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $from;

/**
 * Second person from friendship
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $to;



/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFrom()
{
    return $this->from;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $from
 */
public function setFrom($from)
{
    $this->from = $from;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getTo()
{
    return $this->to;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $to
 */
public function setTo($to)
{
    $this->to = $to;
}

}
```

And User

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="users")
*/
class User
{

/** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $email;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $password;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $name;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $surname;

/** @ORM\Column(type="date")  **/
protected $date;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
protected $sex;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSex()
{
    return $this->sex;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $sex
 */
public function setSex($sex)
{
    $this->sex = $sex;
}


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $email
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSurname()
{
    return $this->surname;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $surname
 */
public function setSurname($surname)
{
    $this->surname = $surname;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $date
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;
}

}
```

I tried to create the new friendship request.

```
    $from = $this->entity_manager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(
        ["id" => $my_id]
    );

    $to = $this->entity_manager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(
        ["id" => $target_user_id]
    );

    /** @var FriendRequest $friend_request */
    $friend_request = new FriendRequest();

    $friend_request->setFrom($from);
    $friend_request->setTo($to);

    $this->entity_manager->persist($friend_request);
    $this->entity_manager->flush();
```

But it does not work. Doctrine shows me error:

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO friendRequest (id) VALUES (?)' with params [186]:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'from' doesn't have a default value.

I tried to print $from ad $to, but they are correct. Is there someone who know what does it mean? I spent a lot of time with it, but I dont know...

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes from the declaration of the $from and $to attributes in the FriendRequest entity class, if you try to update your database model you are going to get an error like this:

[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  Duplicate definition of column 'id' on entity 'FriendRequest' in a field or discriminator column mapping.

Since you have assigned the same name 'id' for two different attributes. Probably you have in your database two columns From and To, but they are not mapping with your model, that's why you get an error saying from doesn't have a default value. Since the column name in the database are not sync with the name of the attributes in your entity.

Assuming you already have a FriendRequest table and you are using 'from' and 'to' as the column names this should be the update of the FriendRequest entity class.

```
class FriendRequest
{

    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /**
    * First person from friendship
    *
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="from", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $from;

    /**
    * Second person from friendship
    *
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="to", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $to;

    ...

}
```